# Move pane to a new window in tmux

Tags: tmux

I know that it's possible in tmux to *join* a window as a pane, but is it possible to move a pane to it's own window (tab)? I tried searching it up the man page but couldn't find it. I guess it is possible doing it through a shell script, but is there some other, more elegant way?

Answer (score 223, accepted):

#### Relevant tmux Commands

- `join-pane -s`
- `join-pane -t`
- `break-pane`

#### Bindings

You could add the following bindings to your `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
## Join windows: <prefix> s, <prefix> j
bind-key j command-prompt -p "join pane from:"  "join-pane -s '%%'"
bind-key s command-prompt -p "send pane to:"  "join-pane -t '%%'"
```

The above can move panes between existing windows.

For breaking a pane to a new window, use `break-pane` <sup>(which can also be bound)</sup>.

#### Alterative Use

All three commands can be used from the tmux's prompt like: `<prefix>+:` then `break-pane`
Or at the shell's prompt <sup>(inside tmux)</sup> with: `tmux break-pane`.

Comment: It's worth noting that you target a pane using the following format:  "mysession:mywindow.mypane" (if in a different session), and "mywindow.mypane" (if in the same session). You can also use "mysession:progname" if the program running in that pane is unique.

Comment: `bind-key !` from the other answer is all I need.

Comment: And what is the difference between `join-pane -s` and `join-pane -t`?

Comment: @JeanPaul well, if the Answer didn't give you context, the tldr; is `-s` == "get the pane from there and bring it here"; while `-t` == "take this current pane and send it there".

Comment: Thanks. I also found by reading the man that if there are several panes in the window we want to import, we can choose the pane by doing for exampe `join-pane -s 4.0` (a bad habit from computer scientists to always want to start numerotation from 0 but it's another issue).

Answer (score 212):

From the commands list, you can see that it's called break-pane and the command is just

> bind-key !

where bind-key is defaulted to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

Comment: is there a away to attach back "breaked" pane?

Comment: @nazikus you can use `join-pane`. If you don't see any bindings for it in `bind-key ?` (I didn't), you can summon the command prompt with `bind-key :` and execute `join-pane -t <destination pane index>`.

Comment: Don't forget the colon! It's `join-pane -t <optional session name>:<destination pane index>` e.g. `join-pane -t :0`

Comment: WOW!! Thanks! :) +1!

Answer (score 14):

In the latest version of tmux, installed from homebrew on OSx - 1.9a - the default key-binding implements join-pane with a menu

```
bind-key          S choose-window "join-pane -v -s "%%""
bind-key          V choose-window "join-pane -h -s "%%""
```

Answer (score 11):

**tmux 1.8 or above:**

If you are intending to go to a "fullscreen" mode, you can use:

<kbd>bind-key</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>

to "zoom in" (and also zoom-out after you finished your work).

Comment: Yes, but if from there I want to keep opening new windows and don't want the old context taking up space, I need to break away.